# Unix code that returns the first number

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

I have a vector of following numbers

```
1_0.011100  1_0.003500  1_0.013700  0_0.011500
```

I would like unix code that selects only the number before the under score.

The outcome should be

```
1  1  1  0
```

and could you please make it applicable to run it over 500 columns?

Answer (score 4):

This will work for as many columns as you need:

```
sed 's/_[0-9.]\+//g'
```

Comment: @MarwahSoliman please stop having irrelevant discussions in the comments. If you have a question about something else, then post a new question. In the meantime, if one of these answers solved the issue you asked about, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join $", /(\d+)_/g'
perl -lne '$,=$"; print /(\d+)_/g'
```

Comment: do I have to apply both lines?

Comment: No. They are independent solutions in their own right. Take your pick.

Comment: how can I apply your code on columns from 8 to 509 what should I write

Comment: @MarwahSoliman your question didn't mention anything about specific columns. Either edit your question, or ask a new one. You might want to take the [tour] or visit the [help] to understand how this site works.